# How to change the image of listview item based on bind value - UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp

I have a listview which bind values using observable collection. listview contains a button with image and text. Based on the text value I want to change the background color of button and also need to change the source of image. How can I achieve this?

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ShopArray}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:CurrentShopList2">
            <Button Background="Green" >
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{x:Bind IsBooksAvailable}"/>
                    <Image  Source="/Assets/booksAvailable.png" Stretch="None" />
                </Grid>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

If the value of `IsBooksAvailable="Yes"`, I want to change the background color of button to green and source of image to  `/Assets/booksAvailable.png`. And if the value of `IsBooksAvailable="No"` I want to change the background color of button to red and hide the image button.

Comment: Hi nsds: have a look there => https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviors/wiki/DataTriggerBehavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the button, you need an IValueConverter. It should look like this:

```
public class BoolToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {

           if ((bool)value)            
               return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255, 0));
           else
               return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Bind the color property of the button to the IsBooksAvailable with this converter.

For the Image, you can do the same, bind the Source property to the text field and, if necessary, use a converter to adjust the text to a correct path. 
But I would prefer storing the images in a byte[] property in the ObservableCollection and use a ByteArrayToImageConverter.

Comment: what is (bool)value)  here? how can I check the Text Yes or No?

Comment: You bind the background property of the button to IsBooksAvailable. That makes no sense because a bool cannot be a brush. So we use a converter. In the convert method the value is the value you bind to, in this case IsBooksAvailable. value is an object, so we have to cast it to a bool. And then we return green if true and red if false. This is what the button in xaml should look like: <Button Background="{Binding IsBooksAvailable,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverter}}"/> But mind that you have to define the converter in the resources of the xaml

Comment: In my case Yes or No is not boolean.they are string values. In the place of "if ((bool)value)"  I want to check if that equals to "Yes" / "No"

Comment: Oh, sorry i was assuming it was a bool. So you only have to cast to a string and write: if((string)value == "Yes"). The rest of the converter can be the same, but i reccomend to catch null and a string which is not "yes" or "no"

Answer (score 0):

Here is other solution - made pure in XAML. Apart from mentioned *Behaviors* this can also be done with *VisualStateManager*:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ShopList}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:ShopItem">
            <UserControl>
                <Button Click="Button_Click">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="AvailableStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Default"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Available">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="ItemGrid.Background" Value="Green"/>
                                    <Setter Target="ItemImage.Source" Value="/Assets/Tick.png"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <StateTrigger IsActive="{x:Bind IsBookAvailable, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid x:Name="ItemGrid">
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold" Text="{x:Bind Title}"/>
                        <Image x:Name="ItemImage" Source="/Assets/NotAvailable.png" Stretch="None" />
                    </Grid>
                </Button>
            </UserControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Added click for some testing:

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var shopItem = (e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement).DataContext as ShopItem;
    shopItem.IsBookAvailable = !shopItem.IsBookAvailable;
}
```

The whole sample you can [check at GitHub](https://github.com/Romasz/UWPSamples/tree/master/ListItemTrigger).